# Is there a good practice to store .config file in OpenWRT?

Tags: linux, config, embedded-linux, openwrt

I'm looking for an approach to store .config file for openwrt? I do not like to store the file in the root dir. Unfortunately in the upstream build, there is nothing about that. Maybe someone has used their own approaches. I would like to see something similar for the implementation `board_defconfig` files in the Linux kernel.
Thanks!